# Android - bitmap tileMode="repeat" not work correct

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a ListView in my project that set a pattern in item's background

my xml drawable

temp_listview_sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                     <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#00000000" android:startColor="#00000000" />
                     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#CCA48300" />
                     <corners android:radius="5.1dp" />
                     <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bg_list1" android:tileMode="repeat" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <layer-list>
             <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#00000000" android:startColor="#00000000" />
                    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="5.1dp" />
                    <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/bg_list" android:tileMode="repeat" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and my code in listview adapter

```
sample_main_menu_layout_item = (ViewGroup) row1.findViewById(R.id.sample_main_menu_layout_item);
        sample_main_menu_layout_item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.temp_listview_sample);
```

but tilemode not works in below android 4

[image](http://axgig.com/images/14726213446653891097.jpg)

excuse me for bad speaking english ;)

also I used these but dont work
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11153248

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500334

I have a selector and 2 layer-list and 2 bitmap in one xml

can anyone help me for fix it?

---

EDIT:

my xml file for listview items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sample_main_menu_layout_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/temp_listview_sample" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_message_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_count_shape"
            android:text="0"
            android:maxHeight="20dp"
           android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="12dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_next"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_previous_item" />
   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip" >
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_text_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" 
            android:gravity="right"/>
     </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip" >
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
     </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please show the xml that you use per listview item? "row1" the inflated/recycled view of the each row that you use in the getView() method, right?

Comment: that right, row1=convertView in getview, yes put xml in below post

Comment: I cant answer to my question :D my xml file is this link http://www.uplooder.net/cgi-bin/dl.cgi?key=e95f189d98c5b69c4fb19c1801ff781f

Comment: I think you've put the wrong xml file, since there is no view there with the id of "sample_main_menu_layout_item" . is it also possible you don't use the "viewHolder" design pattern, as shown on the google IO lecture "the world of listView" ?

Comment: I dont think because it works correct in android 4, but there is a bug in android 1- 2 - 3, in two up link it solves that it is include selector and bitmap but my xml code is include selector and layer-list and bitmap and it doesn't work for me , this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412430/statelistdrawable-and-tiled-bitmap/11153248#11153248

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying. it seems you didn't understand me. the xml file you've shown of the layout that you use per row doesn't have the id of "sample_main_menu_layout_item" , so you are clearly doing something wrong here, or you've put the wrong file.

Comment: sorry, I sent the wrong file, but it is like this, set it in next post

Comment: i've edited your original question to hold the xml file (nothing else was added/modified/removed). you can delete what you've created as an answer, and please try to avoid it next time. anyway, can you please try to explain what doesn't work exactly? maybe show images of what you want to have and what you get?

Comment: tnx , excuse me for bad speak english , I want my items be same this http://www.uploadax.com/images/54731931654434793472.jpg  , but in android 2 or 3 it show same this http://axgig.com/images/14726213446653891097.jpg , how fix it? I know it is a bug in android 1 and 2 and 3, also it show correct in android 4

Comment: why do you have a gradient with complete transparent color ? is it a trick to put the content inside the shape?

Comment: yes, because i dont need to gradient color but I need only to strok and raduce corners   , and a bitmap fill into it , now I problem with this on android lower 4 ,According to this way  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412430/statelistdrawable-and-tiled-bitmap/11153248#11153248  Can you change it So that work for me?

Comment: i don't know why you get this weird behavior. have you tried using a relativeLayout instead of multiple linearLayouts ? also why did you use weight (and of 2), yet you didn't set the width to 0px ? have you also tried Lint (the button that looks like a checkbox with a "V" in it)? maybe it could give you a hint about what's wrong.

Comment: my friend , I dont have problem with xml layout and my problem is tileMode in "temp_listview_sample.xml" that android:tileMode="repeat" dont work! According to my Search it is a bug in old android and Some people have suggested solutions but i think it have to Some change that work for me but I dont know how do it

Comment: ok, sorry. i'm not aware of this issue and i don't know how to fix it. just thought it might help to try other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy my bitmap xml for each view and problem solve Greatly