# tileMode repeat in drawable won't work

Tags: android

I have this drawable resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_stripe"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="false"
    android:filter="false"
    android:gravity="left"
/>
```

used as background here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_world_locked" >
```

Sometimes everything works well, sometimes not (the drawable resource appears in its real small size and not repeated). Why? It's an Android bug? I run this on my HTC Desire Android 2.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately yes - it's Android bug. Check this answer

[Tiled drawable sometimes stretches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336286/tiled-drawable-sometimes-stretches/9500334#9500334)

In short: you should set repeating in Java code instead of XML.

Comment: I was hoping it was not a bug, anyway thank you!