# Android background as drawable : does not repeat

Tags: android, xml, background, repeat, tile

I'm trying to make a background, from an image file.

My **background.xml** file is this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/bg_pat_100_100"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true"
 />
```

and I use this background in my layouts, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".XYZ" 
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >

    <!-- ... layout content ... -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, if I run this in an emulator device, it makes the background repeating, as expected.

But if I run this in a real device, the background is like a single image, streched throughout the screen.

What could be the problem?

### P.S.

I tried removing the application, clearing the eclipse project, deleting R.java. None of them changed the situation.

Comment: If my answer helped you please set it as correct as it will help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its a known bug. Ive encountered with it myself , nothing wrong with your code.

Basically I think you have to set repeating in code not on XML.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336286/tiled-drawable-sometimes-stretches/9500334#9500334) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your Java code, call this function on the layout element that has the attribute `android:background` this will make sure the background drawable is tiled.

```
public static void fixBackgroundRepeat(View view) {
    Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
    if (bg != null) {
        if (bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
            bmp.mutate(); // make sure that we aren't sharing state anymore
            bmp.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
        }
    }
}
```

example:

```
fixBackgroundRepeat(findViewById(R.id.my_xml_tag_that_has_background));
```