# Android Background image is deformed in repeat

Tags: android

I use android:tileMode="repeat" for my textview backgrnound. It is about 1px height image,but in repeat is deformed on left,right side.. 
thanks for help!

screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCXSQ.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/chat_rep"
     android:dither="true" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function with each view that has the background:

```
public static void fixBackgroundRepeat(View view) {
    Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
    if (bg != null) {
        if (bg instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            BitmapDrawable bmp = (BitmapDrawable) bg;
            bmp.mutate(); // make sure that we aren't sharing state anymore
            bmp.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);
        }
    }
}
```

This was an answer posted on this question: 
["Tiled drawable sometimes stretches"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500334/966215)

Comment: TextView messageView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
 messageView.setText(message);
 fixBackgroundRepeat(messageView);


With no changes.. http://2imgs.com/8866a78d5e

                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/repeat_me" />

Comment: Actually, this looks like a perfect opportunity for you to create a 9 patch background image... you shouldn't have to do any of this manually in code.