# Android: Adding lines in edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have this edittext:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:maxLength="170"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.8"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" >
</EditText>
```

When i open it up the writing area is all blank, what i want is to create "lines", like a noteblock, is there any way to add this with code?

Comment: Edit text will proide you only a blank text area to write the data and if you wanted to gice it a look like notebook lines you can use an image for that for make graphics for that so that as the user text increases the text lines increases

Comment: android:maxLines="2"
android:singleLine="false"

Comment: try using set background in edittext

Comment: you can make your drawable with one notebook line, then set its tile mode to repeat and use it as background.

Comment: @rstk how should i write the repeat code?

Comment: Put multiple Edittexts bellow each other and each one with backround of a line at bottom also give gravity as bottom to each that will create effect of writing on a line!

Comment: Please visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524204/Simple-notepad-for-Android. This may help you

Comment: @da_st look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336286/tiled-drawable-sometimes-stretches/9500334#9500334