# Android background stretches instead of repeat

Tags: android, xml, image, background, repeat

I have the following two XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/noise"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newsHeader"
        android:background="@drawable/news_header" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:password="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/noisejpg"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

When I open the main XML, the background is stretched instead of repeated. Why is this happening?

Comment: This answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9500334/1375020. It seems like a bug.

Comment: That did the job, thanks!